# I want help from your on hide button

Tags: javascript, html

how i can hide button after I clicked on it?I'm wait your help

Comment: Instead of writing "I want help from your on..." on each question you should better put more effort into the question itself

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on an additional framework like jQuery you might want to try something like this:

```
<button onclick="this.style.display='none';">Click to hide</button>
```

Some more information about your problem would indeed help others to help you.

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work with me.

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work.I have code I got it from this page: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/.and as you see I have button login and I want to hide this button after I click on it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but on the site you mention, I receive an "Error 404 - Page not found!".